# What does range in descriptive statistics mean

Tags: descriptive-statistics, range

What does high range in my variable mean??. If I have a variable whose range is less ,what does it mean??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(statistics)) in statistics is defined as

$$\operatorname{Range}(X) = \max(X) - \min(X)$$

I you divide the range by $2$, you get [mid-range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-range), one of the measures of the central tendency. Notice that for some software, for example R, what is returned are minimum and maximum (so the data "ranges" from minimum to maximum).

Alternatively, what may be meant is the [interquartile range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range)

$$\operatorname{IQR}(X) = q_{0.75}(X) - q_{0.25}(X)$$

where $q_{0.75}, q_{0.25}$ are third and first [quartiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) respectively. The second case is the range of the $50\%$ "middle" of the data.

In both cases those ranges tell you how spread your data is. The definition using minimum and maximum would obviously be heavily influenced by the extreme values, this may be helpful feature, or misleading property, depending on the nature of the data and your analysis purpose.

Comment: If I have a variable whose range is 10 and same variable with range 5. Which variable should I choose??.Either tye variable with range 10 or range 5?

Comment: @Anees choose for what purpose? Why would you like to choose it based on range?

Comment: It is a question asked to me. If I was given 3 set of data sets(n=10) with ranges 5-10, 5-50,5-8. Which dataset would you choose and why?

Comment: @Anees why would you need to "choose" dataset? For what purpose? Why would you like to do this based on descriptive statistics?

Comment: Maybe if the dataset has high range, it will have higher variance which will help us capture more information from the data...It was asked to test my statistics knowledge.

Comment: @Anees I'm sorry, but for me question like this doesn't make much sense without additional details. The generic answer I'd give is to use all the data, rather then cherry-picking. There is simply not enough details to answer this. Big range may mean that you have outliers, small range may mean that you have biased sample, etc. both may mean that the data is "good" or "bad" depending on context. The value alone is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. So with range we can't decide if that dataset is good or bad, that is what I understood

Comment: @Anees yes, same as with any other descriptive statistic, they just "describe" how it is.